# Order of permutation

Tags: group-theory

I've run into this problem a while ago, and even though I've read lots of topics about it, I still don't seem to understand how order in permutations works. To be specific, I have to find orders of permutations: $$(16)(36) \text{ and } (135)(251)$$

I suppose that the way to do it is to check which power gives me 1 in the end. Sorry if this is confusingly written, I'm very tired. So, here's my attempt:

- $(16)(36)^2 = 1$, so order of permutation should be two, since we're skipping a number, so we get $(1)(6)(3)$;
- $(135)(251)^3 = 1$, so order of permutation should be three, since we're skipping two numbers, so we got $(1)(2)(3)(5) = 1$;

Please tell me if my understanding of the subject is incorrect. My lecture notes tell me that I should get swapped results (3 for the first example, 2 for the second), but I can't figure out why it should be like that. Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The "order" of a permutation is the least number of times that the permutation multiplied by itself will give the identity permutation.  For example, a transposition $(1\; 6)$ will give the identity if you multiply it by itself (second power), so a transposition has "order" two.  This terminology comes from group theory, as you are perhaps already aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-disjoint cycles do not necessarily commute, and in this case we have
$$
 ((16)(36))^2 \neq (16)^2 (36)^2  = 1
$$
and
$$
 ((135)(251))^3 \neq (135)^3 (251)^3 = 1.
$$

To fix this we have to write the permutations as the product of *disjoint* cycles. Then
$$
 (16)(36) = (163)
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 (135)(251) = (12)(35).
$$
Now you can apply your logic to the right hand side of the equations, because disjoint cycles do commute. Then $\mathrm{ord} (163) = 3$ and $\mathrm{ord} ((12)(35)) = 2$.

(More generally we have $\mathrm{ord} (a_1 \dotso a_n) = n$ for every cycle $(a_1 \dotso a_n)$, and if $c_1, \dotsc, c_n$ are disjoint cycles then $\mathrm{ord} (c_1 \dotsm c_n) = \mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{ord}(c_1), \dotsc, \mathrm{ord}(c_n))$.)

Comment: thanks, I think I finally got it! Great, thank you! :)